# Tomcat 7 upgrade war file without context.xml deleting

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, war

i have a trouble situation, my webapp contains an invalid context.xml (missing database credential) to re-use the same war into all my environments (develop, test, production).

My deploying steps are:

1. copy myApp.war into webapps directory
2. edit /etc/tomcat7/myApp.xml (tomcat copy war context.xml into this dir)
3. when i save the myApp.xml file, tomcat7 restart application using new myApp.xml file

When I try to update my application using a new myApp.war file, tomcat7 NOT DEPLOY new sources but REFRESH it using old folder!!!

If i try to remove my directory tomcat delete also .xml

in my situation you can read follow row into catalina.out log:

**Reloading context [/myApp]**

When tomcat7 redeploy an application you can read follow row:

**Undeploying context [/myApp]**

It is a "very" trouble situation!!!

can i re-deploy my new myApp.war without lost my myApp.xml ?

Note: "refresh" application is a tomcat7 topic, when i rewrite war into tomcat6 my application is re-deployed!

Comment: Have you considered using environment variables for the database credentials? That way you could keep the same war file for all envs, and simply pass different values into the env vars, and you won't have to worry about the whole redeploy issues... Just a thought...

Comment: @gsaslis, i have more myApp.war into same tomcat7 instance. How to do it using environment variables?

Comment: do you mean you have dev, test and prod apps all running in the same tomcat instance? That doesn't sound like such a good idea (e.g. What if you cause an OOME in dev? ) Was assuming separate tomcat instance per app..

Comment: sorry @gsaslis but i dont explain this scenario very well. I have 3 tomcat7 instance (develop, test and prod) with multiple "myApp.war". So your solution is inapplicable!!!